# State Level Unemployment Data

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, unemployment

I thought that the St Louis FED was the ultimative resource for macro data, but even they don't appear to have a time series of **state level** unemployment numbers for the United States.

Who does?

Comment: http://www.bls.gov/web/laus/laumstrk.htm ; and Google returns more.

Comment: @Anton I also found that. I should specify im looking for time series.

Comment: Sorry for not having a specific link, but BEA [has](http://www.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?reqid=70&step=1&isuri=1&acrdn=1#reqid=70&step=1&isuri=1&7003=1000&7004=naics&7035=-1&7005=1&7006=xx&7001=11000&7036=-1&7002=1&7090=70&7007=2012&7093=levels) data on *employment* and CPS [includes](https://cps.ipums.org/cps-action/extract_requests/download) microdata on employment status. I hope someone will give a better source.

Comment: BLS does provide time series. I am looking at a decade of monthly data for Delaware both seasonally adjusted and not right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: DE Unemployment Rate Time Series]

The Bureau of Labor Statistics Local Area Unemployment series of data provides monthly figures at the state level from 1976-2014 downloadable as Excel, CSV, or images.

I looked into the following Series:

LASST100000000000003 
LASST100000000000004 
LASST100000000000005 
LASST100000000000006 

LAUST100000000000003 
LAUST100000000000004 
LAUST100000000000005 
LAUST100000000000006

Where LAU meant not seasonally adjusted, and LAS was seasonal, with the 3,4,5,6 standing for labor force, employment, unemployment, and unemployment rate, respectively, and the 10000000000000 (I believe) indicating the region I chose (in this example, the State of Delaware).

You can use the [One Screen Search Tool](http://data.bls.gov/pdq/querytool.jsp?survey=la) to find whatever you need.